# set background image using css() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/twsfag9k/

```
$(function () {
    var string = 'http://i.imgur.com/eHq5oXc.jpg'
    $('div').css('background-image', string);
});
```

What's wrong in my code above? It looks fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var string = 'http://i.imgur.com/eHq5oXc.jpg';

$('div').css('background-image', 'url(' + string + ')');
```

Comment: what if I can;t modify the string?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var string = 'url(http://i.imgur.com/eHq5oXc.jpg)';
    $('div').css('background-image', string);
});
```

Check below fiddle link  :

http://jsfiddle.net/twsfag9k/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can get it only with CSS:

```
div {    
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:pink;
    background: no-repeat url('http://i.imgur.com/eHq5oXc.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/twsfag9k/6/